# Is it dangerous to return MPI_Request and MPI_Status objects by value?

Tags: c++, parameters, mpi

I'm writing a light wrapper in C++ for MPI. To make things easier, I have some functions return an `MPI_Request` object rather than take one as a pointer. The code works fine on my computer, although I'm concerned it could cause problems with a different implementation of MPI.

Below is some example code:

```
template<class T> MPI_Request ireceive(T* data, int count, int source, int tag)
{
    MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Irecv(data, get_mpi_type<T>::mul * count, get_mpi_type<T>::type(), source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    return request;
}
template<class T> MPI_Request ireceive(std::vector<T>& dest, int source, int tag)
{
    MPI_Status status = probe(source, tag);
    int size = get_msg_size<T>(status);
    dest.clear();
    dest.resize(size);
    return ireceive(&dest[0], size, source, tag, status);
}
MPI_Status wait(MPI_Request& request)
{
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Wait(&request, &status);
    return status;
}
MPI_Status test(MPI_Request& request, int& flag)
{
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Test(&request, &flag, &status);
    return status;
}
```

The first two functions directly return a MPI_Request object, and the second two functions return an MPI_Status object. I am concerned that, with another MPI implementation, these functions could cause undefined behavior.

**Is it dangerous to return MPI_Request and MPI_Status objects by value?**

Comment: Jorge, is MPI_Request object with some C++ features or it is just C struct? What does say MPI standard about C++ and MPI_Request?

Comment: This uses a copy constructor to return the data. So, if it works correctly, there is no danger. I assume that the size of the struct is fairly small and copying will not affect performance too much.

Comment: MPI_Request is POD and MPI_Status is POD. It can be safe to copy them if MPI implementation (library) uses data in the structs, not the address of struct (check MPI Standard, check several popular MPI implementations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it dangerous to return MPI_Request and MPI_Status objects by value?

It can result in errors, as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44819846/2411320).

> Will it affect performance?

These structs should not be big enough to downgrade performance, but in general, when passing by reference is a choice, it should be followed.

Comment: Actually copying `MPI_Request` can yield to errors.

Answer (score 3):

`MPI_Status` structure is basically an array of integers that reports the results of a particular communication, be it a point to point receive or an non-blocking operation. Copying this structure is not dangerous, and you can do it using either an assignment or `memcpy`. The performance penalty of copying this should not be a problem, as the typical size of these elements is around 20 bytes (MPI 3.1).

On the other hand, `MPI_Request` is not trivial. I also made some MPI wrappers in C++ for a project (because C++ API is deprecated and not consistent across implementations). `MPI_Request` structures are basically handles (think of it like a pointer) that are used to check the completion status of an operation. If the handle is released (because a non-blocking operation has finished, or because you called either `MPI_Request_free` or `MPI_Cancel`, then the object is no longer valid and `MPI_Request` handle is set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.

In my experience, `MPI_Request` wrapper classes are better made non-copyable. You can still share them using references or pointers. This will save you some debugging time.

See MPI standard document 3.1, section 3.7 Non-blocking communication

> A call to `MPI_TEST` returns `flag = true` if the operation identified by request is complete. In such a case, the status object is set to contain information on the completed operation. If the request is an active persistent request, it is marked as inactive. **Any other type of request is deallocated** and the request handle is set to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`. [...]
>
> One is allowed to call `MPI_TEST` with a null or inactive request argument.  In such a case the operation returns with `flag = true` and empty status.

Note: null or inactive request **is not** an invalid request handle, which for example is the result of releasing `MPI_Request` and setting only one of these copies to `MPI_REQUEST_NULL`.